# How to use webpack if I use script tag in the page to include Vue and Vue Router as global variable

Tags: webpack, vue.js

All:

I am pretty new to webpack, I wonder if I include vue and vue-router in index.html as script tag

```
<script src="/path/to/vue.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/vue-router.js"></script>
```

The reason I need to do it in that way is because:

My currently project disables external NPM and the internal NPM repo does not have vue and vue router, so I have to use script tag way to introduce them in.

But I still want to use webpack to compile other file and bundle them, how can I do that? I add externals field to `webpack.config.js`, but when I run it, it asks me all kinds of dependencies such as vue-loader etcs which are also missing from internal repo.

I wonder how can I do this?

THanks

Comment: Why? If you're using Webpack to bundle your app, you just import `vue` and `vue-router` when and where required

Comment: @Phil My currently project disable external NPM and the internal NPM repo does not have vue and vue router, so I have to use script tag way to introduce them in. Any solution can by pass this?

Comment: If you cannot install dev-dependencies like vue-loader, you cannot build single-file `.vue` components. Sounds like you're trying to do something your current environment is not capable of supporting

Comment: so you only want to use vue and vue-router in index.html? other pages will not use them?

Comment: @Sphinx There is only index.html, no other page. I just want to write single file vue component with ES6 and still compile the whole application into one bundle.js

Comment: _"My currently project disables external NPM and the internal NPM repo does not have..."_ <- why? Can that be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple files in entry object in webpack.config.js

```
entryPoint = {
    app: ['path/to/vue.js', 'path/to/vue-router.js','./index.js'],
};
```

This will make sure that you have both vue and vue-router loaded when you have run index.js (entry point of project).

More on [Webpack entry points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/).

Comment: So webpack will figure out the dependency relationship for me even we compile them as 3 separated entries? The order does not matters?

Comment: in the final build these will be included before index.js file logic